# .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark") vs .format("jdbc")

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hbase, apache-phoenix

I wonder what is the difference of using `.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")` vs .`format("jdbc")` when loading HBase table (through Phoenix) to spark dataframe.

```
val tracesDF = spark.sqlContext.read
  .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
  .option("table", hbaseTblName)
  .option("zkUrl", appConf.getString("zookeeper_url"))
```

vs

```
val tracesDF = spark.sqlContext.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("driver", "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver")
  .option("url", appConf.getString("hbasedb_url"))
```

Another issue I found which related to this issue:

- I create the HBase table through jdbc statement `hbaseCon.createStatement().execute('CREATE TABLE ...)`
- The dataframe of `.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")`  is empty, while `.format("jdbc")` return the data properly
- Need to specify column family [``` tracesDF.select(...,"``B.SAMPLES_BINARY``") ```] when using .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark") but not when using .format("jdbc") [`tracesDF.select(...,"SAMPLES_BINARY")`]